# prevent change orientation in a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I have messaging app like whatsapp & ...
The hierarchy like this :

```
Tab Bar Controller
   Navigation Controller
       View Controller
             Target Controller
```

so we are going to Tabbar like this from appDelegate

```
UITabBarController  *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainTab"];
self.window.rootViewController = ivc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**my problem** 
I want to lock the orientation in some condition in a **Target Controller**
but  `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate`  `supportedInterfaceOrientations`  doesn't call , i have read some post about this but i can't find the correct solution.
the posts like this :
[Lock Screen Rotation in iOS 8](http://koreyhinton.com/blog/lock-screen-rotation-in-ios8.html)

[Handling autorotation for one view controller in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502251/handling-autorotation-for-one-view-controller-in-ios7)

**UPDATE**

after many hour for searching , i found the solution but it's not enough 
this link hint to me , if we use UITabController every thing will change so  , we should call

```
-(NSUInteger)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
{
return navigationController.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
  }

-(NSUInteger)tabBarControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
     {
return ((parentOfTarget*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).supportedInterfaceOrientations;
 }
```

this cause i give notification of change orientation & prevent it, but i will see orientation of status bar .

i think i need to call

```
navigationController.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
```

but it's cause crash ;(

[TabBarController: Orienting views in different orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479184/tabbarcontroller-orienting-views-in-different-orientations)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-supportedInterfaceOrientations' instead of`-shouldAutorotate`.

Later should only be used when orientation is decided at run time. In your case, your view controller will always only support portrait mode.

Next, your navigation controller's delegate must implement following method to return the result of calling `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` on the view controller at the top of the navigation stack.

```
-(NSUInteger)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return navigationController.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

Comment: i have called supportedInterfaceOrientations but non of them called in my ViewController , i will try your hint . ( where i should implement this Delegate , in TagetViewController ?

Comment: any of orientation Delegate not call in my `viewController` , only `wilRotate` & `didRoate` called in my `ViewControoler`, i'm really confused about this.

Comment: @please check it again Bro

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to stop landscape orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); 

    // Use this to allow upside down as well
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

and if you want to use shouldAutorotate delegate method you can use in appdelegate.m .

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

If you are using latest ios then use these methods :-

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    // Return a bitmask of supported orientations. If you need more,
    // use bitwise or (see the commented return).
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    // return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    // Return the orientation you'd prefer - this is what it launches to. The
    // user can still rotate. You don't have to implement this method, in which
    // case it launches in the current orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: it's deprecated & also doesn't call  in my View Controller

Comment: i know its deprecated but its working ... ok you can see my updated answer to this query

Comment: not work yet , it's caused with UINavigationController